# CollapsingToolbarLayout - shadow only when scrolled

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm having a trouble with the CollapsingToolbarLayout. The shadow after the CollapsingToolbarLayout is only shown after scroll.

[image: Before Scroll]

[image: AFter scroll]

Is there a way to make the shadow alwas visible?

Comment: post your code ??

Comment: Post your XML code.